# What is a Ruby/Rails 'hook'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am editing some code, and I see the following:

```
<% hook :login do %>
  <% form_tag user_session_path do  %>
    <p>
      <%= label :user_session, :login, 'Email Address' %><br />
      <%= text_field :user_session, 'login' %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= label :user_session, :password, 'Password' %><br />
      <%= password_field :user_session, 'password' %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <%= check_box :user_session, :remember_me %>
        <%= label :user_session, :remember_me, 'Remember me' %>
      </label>
    </p>

    <p><%= submit_tag 'Log In' %></p>
  <% end %>

  or <%= link_to 'Create a new account', signup_path %> | <%= link_to 'Forgot Password', new_password_reset_path %>
<% end %>
```

What does

```
<% hook :login do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

do?

I spent about 5 minutes Googling and found nothing on this subject.

Comment: It doesn't look like a Rails method. Perhaps some gem or plugin that does this?

Comment: Okay, that could make sense. I am using Spree (and not loving it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a pure Ruby sense, all it's doing is calling a method named **hook**, supplying it one argument and a block.

And after looking through the Spree soure code, yep, here's the method: http://github.com/railsdog/spree/blob/master/core/app/helpers/hook_helper.rb

Without looking further, it's not obvious what this is used for. I'd imagine it's to add some piece of HTML to the built-in template (re-defining what the login form looks like, in this case).

Comment: Ahh, right, a named block called hook. That makes sense. Cool. Blocks are still a bit of a newish concept to me.

Answer (score 1):

In Spree, theme hooks are a way of defining parts of Spree’s default templates that you can easily replace or remove later without actually editing the template files.

See documentation at http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/customization.html#hooks

In your example above, the hook is called *:login*. If you wanted to add a heading before the login form, you could use the hook to achieve this without modifying the template.

Add this...

```
class YourAppHooks < Spree::ThemeSupport::HookListener
  insert_before :login, :text=>'<h1>Ahoy!!!</h1>'.html_safe
end
```

...to the file...

> RAILS_ROOT/vendor/extensions/your_app/lib/your_app_hooks.rb